# PostgreSQL Dataabase Specific Parameters

Tags: postgresql, psql

Here is the situation-
Step wise -

1. Created a database called test.
2. Ran the command :

ALTER DATABASE test SET work_mem TO '128MB';

How can I check this updated value apart from logging to test database and running the command show work_mem? Is there any view which can show the updated value of work_mem for specific database?

I tried,

\c test postgres
show work_mem;

and it showed 128MB as value.

Expectation - Looking for a view which can show the same value for specific database?

Comment: you can only access the actual database, you are looged in, so you would need to log in every database to run it, and how many times do you actually want to run that command?

Comment: Got below query from Richard -

SELECT * FROM pg_db_role_setting;  

(All Credit to Richard)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a question like this you can save yourself time and possible misleading "answers" by checking the official documentation.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html

I went to the "system catalogs" section from the main contents page and searched for any mention of settings.

```
rota_exp1=> SELECT * FROM pg_db_role_setting;
┌─────────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ setdatabase │ setrole │                setconfig                 │
├─────────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│       16385 │       0 │ {"search_path=rota, core",work_mem=32MB} │
└─────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

rota_exp1=> SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16385;
┌───────────┐
│  datname  │
├───────────┤
│ rota_exp1 │
└───────────┘
```